# NGINX + HTTP2 + ALPN (ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol and No ALPN negotiated)

Tags: nginx, http2, alpn

the protocol http2 is not working and I cannot see exactly where the error is.

server {
listen 80  ;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
listen 443  ssl http2;
...
}

curl:

```
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
*  CApath: none
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [91 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [4980 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
{ [333 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
{ [4 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
} [70 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [16 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [16 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
```

OpenSSL

```
SSL handshake has read 5602 bytes and written 485 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
```

nginx -V

```
bash-5.1$ nginx -V

nginx version: nginx/1.19.10
built by gcc 11.2.1 20220219 (Alpine 11.2.1_git20220219)
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022
TLS SNI support enabled
--with-http_v2_module enabled
```

could someone help me?